# How to send sensor values to Android app?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, spi

I'm reading some sensor values over SPI in my raspberry, and saving them.
The method I'm using to save is:

```
string IntToString (int number)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << number;
    return oss.str();
}

int main(void)
{
    ad7490Spi a2d("/dev/spidev0.0", SPI_MODE_0, 1000000, 16);
    int i = 5;
    int a2dVal = 0; 
    int a2dChannel = 0;
    unsigned char data[3];

    //ofstream myfile ("/var/www/html/Sensors/Sensor1.txt");

    //if (myfile.is_open())
    //{ ...


    ...
    //myfile.close();
```

Now I want to send them to an android app  I've created. I want that app to get these values and plot them, via achartengine.
The problem is that I'm completely in the dark about the method I should use to do this.
Could you guys give some hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your setting:

- If your android app will **connect to raspberry only from the same local network**: an "easy" approach is to set up a server on your rasp, and make the android app connect to it to retrieve the data. It can be as complex as building your own server (using some tool like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)) or as easy as setting up an FTP server where you store files with the data.
- **If you want to access the data of your rasp from any place**: then it is easier to set up a server in the cloud to which the rasp uploads the data, and then the android app downloads it. You need to take care at least of router port traversing if you want something usable.

Bear in mind that the second option is also useful for the first case, so it may be the way to go. In that case, I would not recommend you setting your own infrastructure, but using something already made.

In this direction, one interesting solution is [Lhings](http://www.lhings.com), a cloud for internet of things that offers client libraries in [C](https://github.com/lhings/lhings-c-linux) and [Java](http://support.lhings.com/Java-Library.html) so that you can easily connect your device to it, and also a [REST API](http://support.lhings.com/Lhings-API-Documentation.html) you can use to access the data from your Android app. It is dead easy to use, reliable and free up to 3 devices, so it may fit your requirements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it helps!